# Convert jquery to javascript to highlight parent div of radio button/checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code adds a class to the parent of the checkbox / radio button to highlight the radio button along with the label.

Here is the jQuery code which I need to convert to JavaScript.
I am new to both jQuery and JavaScript.

Any pointers will be appreciated !!

```
$('form input[type=checkbox]').click ( function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (this.checked)
    {   $(this).parent().addClass("highlight"); }
    else
    { $(this).parent().removeClass("highlight");    }
})

$('form input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().parent().find('label.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
});
```

Comment: There are numerous jquery->js sites that you can use for this, here's one: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Also this site is for asking question to solve problems. And not to ask experts to rewrite your code because you don't want to. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to this.

But I am sure this is not the most efficient code so if you can think of better options then do let me know.

```
   function checkBox(obj) {
   object=obj;

   if (object.checked){
    object.parentElement.classList.add("highLight1");
   }
   else {
    object.parentElement.classList.remove("highLight1");
   }
   }


   function highlight(obj) {
   object = obj;

   var radios = document.getElementsByName("A1");

   for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
     if(radios[i].checked){
    radios[i].parentElement.classList.add("highLight1");
    }
    else {
        radios[i].parentElement.classList.remove("highLight1");
    }
   }
   }
```